# How to grab some data from returned html in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Suppose i got returned some `html` in variable `data`.
In that variable i have

`<h1> Title </h1>`

Now i want to grab that text `Title` and remove `<h1> Title </h1>` from variable data

how can i achieve that in jquery

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript library. JavaScript has rich support for text manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)
to convert the string to an XML document and then run DOM manipulation using jQuery

```
var XML= $.parseXML(data);
var title = $(XML).find('h1').text(); //Get the text inside h1 tags.
$(XML).find('h1').remove(); // Remove the h1 tags
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QNnLe/

Comment: Actually it's not true that valid HTML is always valid XML, but I liked the solution :)

Comment: I am not paring to XML i think that may be the reason its not working

Comment: `.text()` returns the innertText only use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) instead.. and see the example http://jsfiddle.net/QNnLe/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can `wrap` the contents into a dummy element, get that element and then use `find` to find the content you are looking for:

```
var data = "<h1> Title </h1>";    
console.log($(data).wrap('<div />').parent().find('h1 ').text()); // Title

var data = "sssssss  <h1> Title </h1> aaaaaaaaaa";    
console.log($(data).wrap('<div />').parent().find('h1').text()); //Title
```

The wrapping is useful if the `data` isn't perhaps wrapped inside an element already.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/VWnVj/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var title = $(data).text();
```

Comment: There is lot more html in variable `data` so i can't use text

Comment: @user824981 Can you give us another example of how the data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
data = data.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
```